# Does Galaxybase's API support the ability to sort the attribute values of query results?

Tags: graph-databases

Does Galaxybase's interface support the ability to sort the attribute values of query results? If so, what should be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. If you are using the Java API, the return is an iterator, which can be done using the functions of the Java language if sorting is required; If you call cypher directly, then you can use the sorting function of the cypher language.